# ¿Como filtrar en JTable registros por rango de fecha desde una fecha hasta otra fecha?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

Estoy haciendo un proyecto y en este proyecto hago consultas de clientes proveedores y facturas (compras ventas)

En la consulta de facturas compras y facturas ventas yo realizo una consulta donde me muestre las facturas de un de un mes para después hacer un reporte o imprimir la lista de las factura de ese mes

Este es el formulario (ConsultasVentas)
[image: Formulario (ConsultasVentas)]
CODIGO BOTON BUSCAR

```
String consulta="" ;
    if (fecha.isSelected()==true){
        cant.setText(""+datos.getRowCount());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
        Date fechaD = desde.getDate();
        Date fechaH = hasta.getDate();
        String fecD = sdf.format(fechaD);
        String fecH = sdf.format(fechaH);

        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        modelo.addColumn("Id");
        modelo.addColumn("Fecha_Comp");
        modelo.addColumn("Nro_Comp");
        modelo.addColumn("Cliente_Id");
        modelo.addColumn("Detalle");
        modelo.addColumn("Importe_Neto");
        modelo.addColumn("Importe_IVA");
        modelo.addColumn("Importe_Total");
        datos.setModel(modelo);
        String sql= "";
        sql=" SELECT * FROM Facturas_Ventas WHERE Fecha_Comp BETWEEN  "+fecD+" AND "+fecH+"";
        try{
            Statement st = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            String [] registro = new String[8]; 
            while(rs.next()){

                registro[0]=rs.getString("Id");
                registro[1]=rs.getString("Fecha_Comp");
                registro[2]=rs.getString("Nro_Comp");
                registro[3]=rs.getString("Cliente_Id");
                registro[4]=rs.getString("Detalle");
                registro[5]=rs.getString("Importe_Neto");
                registro[6]=rs.getString("Importe_IVA");
                registro[7]=rs.getString("Importe_Total");

                modelo.addRow(registro);

            }
            datos.setModel(modelo);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
                }

    }
    if (cli.isSelected()==true){
        String clienteB = cliente.getText();
        //consulta = "SELECT * FROM Facturas_Ventas WHERE Cliente_Id='"+clienteB+"'";
        clientetext.setText("");
        cliente.setText("");
        Tabla(clienteB);
        cant.setText(""+datos.getRowCount());
    }
    else{
        Tabla(""); 
        cant.setText("");
    }
```

---

[image: Esto fue lo que hice que se busque por mes y año]

Esto fue lo que hice que se busque por mes y año

---

lo que quiero hacer es mostrar mostrar todas las facturas de un solo mes ordenado de forma ascendente para después hacer el reporte con las facturas ejemplo: si tengo facturas de enero - febrero - marzo y hacer la consulta para que me muestre solamente febrero.

Comment: Has dejado la pregunta un poco en el aire... ¿No está funcionando la query? ¿La fecha almacenada en la BBDD tiene el formato que aplicas en el código?

Comment: Todo lo que deseas mostrar o como lo deses mostrar y sea de manera ascendente o descendente de un campo fecha o cualquier otro campo en el JTable lo puedes hacer mediante un procedimiento o una consulta en la base de datos.

Comment: Ya le busque una solución